# Email Formatted Array

Tags: arrays, email, powershell

I got a script that creates two arrays (each has 1 column and variable number of lines). I want to format these two arrays and e-mail it to an Outlook account. Code and sample data below.

```psh
$Values2 = @(Get-Content *\IdealOutput.csv) 

$OutputLookUp2 = @()
foreach ($Value in $Values2) {
    $OutputLookUp2 += $Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($Value,$range4,3,$false)
}

$Excel.Workbooks.Close()
$Excel.Quit()

$EmailFrom = "sample@sample.com"  
$EmailTo = "sample@sample.com"
$EmailBody = "$Values2 $OutputLookup2" 
$EmailSubject = "Test"
$Username = "sample"
$Password = "sample"

$Message = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage `
    ($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $EmailSubject, $EmailBody)
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient `
    ("smtp.outlook.com", portnumber) #Port can be changed
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential `
    ($Username, $Password);
$SMTPClient.Send($Message)
```

Both `$OutputLookUp2` and `$Values2` are one column with variable number of lines.

Example:

```
$Outputlookup2 = 
X1 
X2

$Values2 = 
Y1 
Y2
```

I would like the output to the body of the e-mail to be:

```
X1 Y1
X2 Y2
```

And I would like to avoid HTML as it will be sent via text as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming my interpretation is correct this seems simple enough. For every `$Values2`, which is just a line from a text file, find its similar value in the open spreadsheet. You are have the loop that you need. Problem is you are building the item lists independent of each other.

```psh
$Values2 = @(Get-Content *\IdealOutput.csv) 

$OutputLookUp2 = @()
foreach ($Value in $Values2){
    $OutputLookUp2 += "$Value $($Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($Value,$range4,3,$false))"
}
```

Now `$OutputLookUp2` should contain your expected output in array form.

If the array does not work you could also just declare it as a string and the add newlines as you are building it. You will notice the `` "`r`n" `` at the end of the string.

```psh
$Values2 = @(Get-Content *\IdealOutput.csv) 

$OutputLookUp2 = ""
foreach ($Value in $Values2){
    $OutputLookUp2 += "$Value $($Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($Value,$range4,3,$false))`r`n"
}
```

In both example you can just flip the order of the `$value` and the lookup easy. If you need a header you can add that when you declare `$OutputLookUp2`.

**There is always room for improvement**

If you want to take this a little further in the direction that [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers)  was eluding to...

```psh
$OutputLookUp2 = Get-Content *\IdealOutput.csv | ForEach-Object{
    "$_ $($Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($_,$range4,3,$false))"
} | Out-String
```

Comment: Appending to an array in a loop performs poorly and should be avoided. Also, [`MailMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5k0ddab0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) expects the body as a string, not a string array, so you may want to add an `Out-String` to the first example.

Comment: Was trying to adapt his code without making drastic changes. Using the pipe would be preferential and achievable here is your point @AnsgarWiechers?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I'm not sure if my update is better or what you meant. Would appreciate feedback if you have any.

Comment: Yes, I'd consider a pipeline the more elegant approach. You could streamline it even more like this: `$output = gc input.csv | % { '{0} {1}' -f $_, $Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup($_, $range4, 3, $false) } | Out-String`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I had originally considered the format operator but decided against it because of the specific issue the OP was having. Trying to keep it simple. Ease him into it. `| Out-String` is easier than ``-join "`r`n"`` for sure though